# Origine dell'espressione "breve storia triste"

Tags: phrase-origin

L'espressione

> Breve storia triste.

è spesso usata sui social network come cappello per, come dice appunto l'espressione, il racconto di un evento sfortunato solitamente accaduto all'autore del messaggio.

È un'espressione di cui esiste un'origine unica ed identificabile (a cui i primi utilizzatori si rifacevano esplicitamente, come in una citazione), o si è semplicemente affermata, tra tutti i possibili modi di introdurre un racconto di sventura, per un'emergenza casuale (mista ai meccanismi viralizzanti dei social)?

Comment: Meta: non sono un assiduo di questo StackExchange, ma mi sarei aspettato dei tag come "meme", "social-network", "internet-language" da usare qui. C'è qualcosa di simile?

Comment: Interessante. Una possibilità è che sia nata come variante di una o più altre espressioni. Mi viene in mente, per pura assonanza, “Piccola storia ignobile”, canzone di Guccini del 1976.

Answer (score 2):

Provo a rispondere alla mia stessa domanda.

***In breve***: l'espressione sembra affermarsi in un momento specifico a fine 2013. Prima di allora non appare mai casualmente né sui social né sui libri, il che mi fa pensare ad un'origine definita piuttosto che ad un'emergenza casuale. Quale sia questa origine, però, non mi è chiaro.

#### Twitter

Da Twitter osservo che l'espressione, nella sua forma rigida (usata come cappello a sé stante), non compare fino al 2013 inoltrato: [i due tweet precedenti Settembre](https://twitter.com/search?q=%22Breve%20storia%20triste%22%20until%3A2013-09-30%20since%3A2006-01-01&src=typed_query) sono dei falsi positivi.

**A Ottobre 2013 compare il primo tweet che usa l'espressione come cappello**:

> *Breve storia triste*
>
> - Dai, ci sentiamo domani.
>
> Domani:
>
> -
>
> — Regina del divano [@Reginadeldivano](https://twitter.com/Reginadeldivano), [23 ottobre 2013](https://twitter.com/Reginadeldivano/status/393040501412466690)

Ad inizio Novembre basterà guardare i soli primi 2 giorni [per trovare ben 4 tweet](https://twitter.com/search?q=%22Breve%20storia%20triste%22%20until%3A2013-11-03%20since%3A2013-10-31&src=typed_query), tutti della forma

> Breve storia triste:
>
> <un singolo nome o pronome>
>
> Fine.
>
> — Vari utenti Twitter, 1 e 2 novembre 2013

Dal [4 novembre alla fine dell'anno](https://twitter.com/search?q=%22Breve%20storia%20triste%22%20until%3A2013-12-31%20since%3A2013-11-04&src=typed_query) il messaggio si ripete ed evolve. La chiusura – "Fine." – viene talvolta omessa; si nota l'affermarsi di brevi conversazioni riportate con discorso diretto (2-4 battute), o di sequenze di azioni espresse ognuna con un periodo semplice.

[Nel 2014](https://twitter.com/search?q=%22Breve%20storia%20triste%22%20until%3A2014-12-31%20since%3A2014-11-04&src=typed_query) il formato è ormai diventato abbastanza libero, ma rimane "Breve storia triste" (seguito da punto o da due punti, e talvolta da un capoverso) ad inizio tweet. Questa forma abbastanza libera è circa la stessa che si osserva tuttora.

❧

C'è da notare che il primo tweet (di @Reginadeldivano) non sembra essere stato eccessivamente famoso (84 retweet mentre scrivo), per cui **non credo che l'origine dell'espressione, e di questa particolare forma di messaggio ironico, sia avvenuta su Twitter**: probabilmente lo stesso formato si stava affermando altrove (immagino su Facebook – ma forse no: vedi sotto – o sui mass media).

Si osserva inoltre che, quello di cui oggi mi sembra sia rimasto solo l'elemento di apertura come espressione a sé stante ("Breve storia triste"), era inizialmente un formato molto più rigido. Questo non dimostra, ma sembra avvalorare, l'ipotesi di una singola origine "celebre".

#### Facebook

Usando la ricerca per "post" su Facebook con filtro "2013" trovo meno risultati che su Twitter. Sono tutti datati Dicembre, quindi successivi all'ondata di Twitter, e con il formato semi-rigido che si osservava in questo periodo su Twitter. Un risultato che appare più volte è:

> Breve storia triste:
>
> Domani è lunedì.
>
> Fine.

Sembrerebbe quindi che l'espressione non sia nata su Facebook. Tuttavia non sono certo che la ricerca interna a Facebook riporti sempre una selezione esaustiva dei risultati. C'è inoltre la possibilità che le prime manifestazioni fossero veicolate tramite immagini contententi testo, come era comune su Facebook, e (sebbene Facebook usi la lettura dei contenuti dell'immagine) potrebbero essere sfuggite a questa ricerca.

#### Google Books

Curiosamente, l'espressione non sembra aver ancora raggiunto il corpus di libri cercabile con Google Ngram Viewer: [la ricerca *case insensitive* di "breve storia triste"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=breve+storia+triste&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&case_insensitive=on&corpus=33&smoothing=3&direct_url=) per il periodo 1800-2019 non riporta alcun risultato.

Alcuni risultati compaiono cercando in Google Books direttamente: ["breve storia triste"](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22breve+storia+triste%22), di cui una mezza dozzina sembrano rilevanti (tutti relativi agli anni 2018-2021). Tra questi, ["Breve storia triste (del mondo)"](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/Breve_storia_triste_del_mondo/__qtDwAAQBAJ?hl=en), libro di Nina Verdelli edito nel 2019 da Baldini-Castoldi.